# Are these two metric spaces complete?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $J$ be an arbitrary non-empty set of indices, and let $\mathbb{R}^J$ denote the set of all the $J$-tuples of real numbers (i.e. the set of all the functions $x \colon J \to \mathbb{R}$, where we denote $x(\alpha)$ by $x_\alpha$, for each $\alpha \in J$). Now let the function $\tilde{\rho} \colon \mathbb{R}^J \times \mathbb{R}^J \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as follows: 
$$ \tilde{\rho}( x, y) \colon= \sup \left\{ \ \min \left\{ \ \vert x_\alpha - y_\alpha \vert, \ 1 \ \right\} \ \colon \ \alpha \in J \ \right\} \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \colon= \left(x_\alpha \right)_{\alpha \in J}, \ y \colon= \left(y_\alpha \right)_{\alpha \in J} \in \mathbb{R}^J.$$
This function $\tilde{\rho}$ is of course a metric on $\mathbb{R}^J$, called the uniform metric. Is the metric space $\left( \ \mathbb{R}^J, \  \tilde{\rho} \ \right)$ complete?

My effort:

Let $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\left( \ \mathbb{R}^J, \  \tilde{\rho} \ \right)$, and let $x_n \colon= \left( x_{\alpha n} \right)_{\alpha \in J}$, for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Then, given any real number $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a natural number $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that 
$$ \tilde{\rho}(x_m, x_n ) < \epsilon \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that } \ m> N \ \mbox{ and } \ n> N. $$
Let's assume that $0< \epsilon < 1$.

Let $\beta \in J$. Then for all $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m > N$ and $n > N$, we have 
$$\epsilon > \tilde{\rho}(x_m, x_n) \geq  \min \left\{ \  \left\vert x_{\beta m} - x_{\beta n} \right\vert, \ 1 \ \right\} = \left\vert x_{\beta m} - x_{\beta n} \right\vert,$$
which shows that the sequence $\left(x_{\beta n} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and so this sequence converges to some real number $x_\beta$.

Now since our $\beta \in J$ was arbitrary, let us define
$x \colon= \left( x_\alpha \right)_{\alpha \in J}$.

Is this logic correct so far? If so, then how to proceed from here, especially if the index set  $J$ is infinite?

Now let's take $J$ to be the set $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers, and let's denote $\mathbb{R}^J$ by $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ and define the function $D \colon \mathbb{R}^\omega \times \mathbb{R}^\omega \to \mathbb{R}$ by the formula
$$ D(x, y) \colon = \sup \left\{ \frac{ \min \left\{ \ \left\vert x_\alpha - y_\alpha  \right\vert, \ 1 \ \right\}}{\alpha } \ \colon \ \alpha  \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\} \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \colon= \left( x_\alpha  \right)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}}, \ y \colon= \left( y_\alpha \right)_{ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\omega.$$
Then $D$ is also a metric on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$, and the topology induced by $D$ is the same as the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. Is the metric space $\left( \ \mathbb{R}^\omega, \ D \ \right)$ complete?

Let $\left(x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $x_n \colon= \left( x_{\alpha n} \right)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a Cauchy sequence in $\left( \ \mathbb{R}^\omega, \ D \ \right)$. Let $\beta$ be a fixed natural number.

Then, given any real number $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a natural number $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that
$$ D(x_m, x_n) < \frac{ \epsilon}{ \beta} \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, n \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that } \ m > N \ \mbox{ and } \  n > N. $$
Let's assume that $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Then for all natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $m, n > N$, we have 
$$\left\vert x_{\beta m} - x_{\beta n} \right\vert < \epsilon,$$
from which it follows that the sequence $\left( x_{\beta n} \right)_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers and therefore this sequence converges to some real number $x_\beta$.

Since our $\beta \in \mathbb{N}$ was arbitrary, we can define an element $x \in \mathbb{R}^\omega$ as $$x \colon= \left( x_\alpha \right)_{\alpha \in \mathbb{N}}.$$

Is my logic correct so far? If so, then how to proceed from here?

What if, in either of the above two cases, we replace $\mathbb{R}$ by an arbitrary complete metric space (and replace $\vert \cdot \vert$ by the corresponding distance of course)? Do we still have a metric in either case? And, if so, is (are) this (these) metric(s) complete?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your logic is correct so far, for both metrics. Actually, your questions are answered (positively) [here](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/848204501356650/FTARnotas_7complete.pdf). There (in theorem 7.11) you can also find the argument to show the Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n\subset \mathbb{R}^J$ converges to $x$, and thus, conclude $(\mathbb{R}^J,\tilde{\rho})$ is complete.

To conclude that $(\mathbb{R}^\omega,D)$ is a complete metric space, let $x=(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathbb{N}}$ be the pointwise limit of the Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n\subset \mathbb{R}^\omega$. Let $1>\epsilon>0$ and $\alpha_0$ s.t. $\frac{1}{\alpha_0}<\epsilon$. Since 
$$
D(x_n,x)=\sup_\alpha \left\{\frac{\min\{1,|x_{n\alpha}-x_\alpha|\}}{\alpha}\right\}
$$
we only need to worry about $|x_{n\alpha}-x_\alpha|$ for $\alpha\in\{1,...\alpha_0\}$. Since $(x_{n\alpha})_n$ converges to $x_\alpha$ for all those indices, then $\exists N,\forall n>N, \forall \alpha \in \{1,...,\alpha_0\},|x_{n\alpha}-x_\alpha|<\epsilon$. Hence, we have shown that
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N, \forall n>N, D(x_n,x)<\epsilon 
$$
ie $x_n\to x$ in $(\mathbb{R}^\omega,D)$.